# DB Query Commands are producing strange sql queries

Tags: go, go-gorm, cockroachdb

I have my model as:

```
type Report struct {
    ID    int     `json:"id,omitempty" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Title *string `json:"title" gorm:"not null"`
}
```

I have initialized variable `report` as `var report Report` I have successfully auto migrated this model as database table and have populated database as `sql INSERT` using GORM's `db.Create(&report)`.

The problem I am facing is while trying query commands. Every query commands supported by GORM such as `db.Find(&report)` , `db.First(&report, 1)` is resulting to queries such as folows:

```
SELECT * FROM "reports"  WHERE "reports"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ((id = $1))
SELECT * FROM "reports"  WHERE "reports"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ((id = $1))
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE (reports.deleted_at IS NULL) AND ((id = $1))
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE (reports.deleted_at IS NULL) AND ((id = $1))
SELECT 0 done
```

I am unable to query database. I am using GORM with cockroach db. This works fine when using GO pq driver and raw sql commands.

Answer (score 2):

The `deleted_at` column is a part of GORM's [base `gorm.Model`](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/models.html#conventions) struct and its [soft delete](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#delete) feature. Are you using `gorm.Model` somewhere that we can't see in this example? This isn't supposed to happen unless you either define a field named `DeletedAt` or embed a `gorm.Model` in your model struct.

Comment: exactly what I am confused with. I have not defined any field named `DeletedAt` nor I'm using `gorm.Model`. I have only defined one `Report struct` and wrapped gorm under `httprouter` to insert and query each.  `db.create` works fine. using error function in `db.Find` returns `record not found`. Btw I derived my code closely based on example-orm package provided by cockroachlabs.

Comment: I tried again but could not figure out the problem. Examples provided as **Query With Where (Struct & Map)** in GORM's documentation also did not work. Meanwhile, I went with GORM's raw query as `db.Raw("SELECT * FROM reports").Scan(&report)` and only this seems to work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Since the model has the field deleted_at, gorm is using the **soft delete ability** automatically. You can use `Unscoped`

```
 db.Unscoped().Find(&reports)
```

Which is the same as running the raw query

```
db.Raw("SELECT * FROM reports").Scan(&reports)
```